# Add user details to smart Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, web3js, ether, etherscan

What is the best way to store users data on smart contract? Suppose we have n number of users and we want to store each username and his other details, should we have to create a smart contract individually for every user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a struct like so:

```
struct User {
    uint256 id;
    bytes32 name;
    // other stuff

    bool set; // This boolean is used to differentiate between unset and zero struct values
}
```

And create a mapping:

```
mapping(address => User) public users;
```

You could also use other values as index, but this is just for demonstration.

Now, to create a user, use a function like this:

```
function createUser(address _userAddress, uint256 _userId, bytes32 _userName) public {
    User storage user = users[_userAddress];
    // Check that the user did not already exist:
    require(!user.set);
    //Store the user
    users[_userAddress] = User({
        id: _userId,
        name: _userName,
        set: true
    });
}
```

And done!

**EDIT**
As you stated in the comments, you want to store the hash of user information in a smart contract. That is even simpler: just store the hashes in a mapping.

This is the mapping you use to store the hashes in:

```
mapping(uint256 => bytes32) public userDataHashes;
```

Now, the function to set a hash for a user id becomes:

```
function storeUserDataHash(uint256 _userId, bytes32 _dataHash) public {
    userDataHashes[_userId] = _dataHash;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP asked about contract users, could be just any users in general. So a mapping to address may not be appropriate. But, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: As stated, this is just for demonstration

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @henkiedoodle. Here's my application model. There are N general users who don't know anything about smart contracts. They will login to a portal, submit their documents, there will be a function in backend that will convert file content to hash using keccak256 and will store the file hash in smart contract. I am confused in should every time we have to create a new smart contract when a new user will login to portal?

Comment: No, you should store the information in a mapping. They are perfect for this application.

Comment: But in that case contract address would be same for each user, how a user would be identified individually?

Comment: You use one contract for all the users. To differentiate between users, pull them out of the mapping using their user id: `bytes32 currentUserHash = userDataHashes[currentUsersId]`. Or in web3.js: `theContract.userDataHashes(currentUsersId)`