# How to store user specific data in ethereum private chain

Tags: solidity

I want to store data specific to each user, like a hash of his ipfs file. How to store this data so that later i can query with user id.

Comment: [Check this out](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/45558/28303)

Answer (score 4):

Create a smart contract with a mapping variable, a setter, and a getter (the getter is not really necessary as solidity will create it for you).

```
pragma Solidity 0.4.23;

contract storeData{
    address public admin;
    mapping(uint256 => bytes32) public userData;

    constructor(){
        admin = msg.sender;
    }

    function saveData(uint256 userId,bytes32 fileHash) returns (bool){
        userData[userId] = fileHash;
        return True
    }

    function getData(uint256 userId) returns (bytes32){
        return userData[userId]
    }

}
```

if you need more data to be stored take a look at [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45557/add-user-details-to-smart-contract)

Hope it helps.